# pre-release test error on hudson

Tags: ros, ros-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the fancy code release system for the first time and it seems to be very impressive how everything gets auto-magically generated for you however I ran into a problem last week when I tried a pre-release test.

I should mention that I'm the repository maintainer and so I first followed the [Repository Setup Instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/release/Setup/Repository) - so just bear in mind that the problem may not be with the stack itself but maybe it's a problem with the entire repo configuration in the rosdistro.

I tried to run a Hudson Pre-Release test and I got the following error in Diamiondback and Unstable on all of the platforms. It doesn't seem like it even got up compiling code so I don't know where to start debugging the problem...

> Command failed: Command '['sudo', 'chroot', '/home/rosbuild/chroot/prerelease_unstable_sbpl_arm_planning_lucid_amd64', 'su', 'rosbuild', '-s', '/bin/bash', '-c', "HUDSON_URL='http://build.willowgarage.com/' BUILD_URL='http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_unstable_sbpl_arm_planning_lucid_amd64/1/' BUILD_TAG='hudson-prerelease_unstable_sbpl_arm_planning_lucid_amd64-1' JOB_NAME='prerelease_unstable_sbpl_arm_planning_lucid_amd64' BUILD_ID='2011-03-17_14-10-59' BUILD_NUMBER='1' JOB_URL='http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_unstable_sbpl_arm_planning_lucid_amd64/' EXECUTOR_NUMBER='0' /tmp/script.sh"]' returned non-zero exit status 255
> ectory_filters', 'pr2_kinematics']
> Adding dependencies of stack sensor_msgs
> Command failed, shutting down chroot
> Shutting down

You can also check out the entire [hudson console output](http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_unstable_sbpl_arm_planning_lucid_amd64/1/console).

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9530/pre-release-test-error-on-hudson/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is failing because "sensor_msgs" is not a stack.  "common_msgs" is.

You can recalculate your stack dependencies by running:

```
roscd yourstack
roscreate-stack .
```

Note: we don't auto-calculate stack dependencies because this prevents dependencies from accidentally sneaking in.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2011-03-23**:
That was the problem. I had sensor_msgs and common_msgs listed in the stack.xml. I won't be as careless in the future.

Thanks.